# React Native Navigation issues in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I have installed ***react-native-navigation*** package for navigation in react native. After that I didn't like it and try use another package for navigation. But when I tried to **uninstall** this package and tried to run the app, it gives the following errors as given below. I didn't do anything, I had just uinstalled this ***react-native-navigation*** package from npm.

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\messaging\ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainActivity.java:4: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
                                ^
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainActivity.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class NavigationActivity
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:9: error: package com.reactnativenavigation does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
                                ^
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:10: error: package com.reactnativenavigation.react does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationPackage;
                                      ^
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:35: error: package com.reactnativenavigation.react does not exist
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
                                      ^
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
                                     ^
  symbol: class NavigationApplication
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainActivity.java:11: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainActivity.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      super.onCreate(null);
      ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class MainActivity
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
      new NavigationReactNativeHost(this) {
          ^
  symbol:   class NavigationReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:45: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:50: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
S:\Collab\ReactNative\Edesign\android\app\src\main\java\com\edesign\MainApplication.java:53: error: no suitable constructor found for PackageList(<anonymous NavigationReactNativeHost>)   
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
```

Is there any solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you uninstalled `react-native-navigation` from npm, you should also revert back [installation on Android](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing#2-update-mainactivityjava)

- Update MainActivity.java

1. remove this line:
   `import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;`
2. Instead add this:
   `import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;`
3. Also, extends from `ReactActivity`, not `NavigationActivity`

- Update MainApplication.java

1. Remove these:
   `import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;` 
   `import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;`
2. Update this line:
   `public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication`
   to this one:
   `public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {`
3. Update this line:
   `new NavigationReactNativeHost(this) {` 
   to this one:
   `new ReactNativeHost(this) {`
4. `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false); // add this one
  initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
}
```

Comment: How do I revert that, can you show me some more details on revert back `installation to android` please.

Comment: @Sumanl46, I updated the answer. pls check out.